# Sql server 2008 Track If a user logged in per day

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I need to write a function that writes if a user has logged in per day to a database table.

Whenever a user logs into my website i need my function to fire and grab his UserId and the current datetime. If a user logs in twice in one day it has to fire the function again and write a new line. The end result i need is a database table with each login that i can sort per day per user.

This is my function, I made it fire on the LoggedIn Event of my login control

```
CREATE PROCEDURE loginProc
    @UserId uniqueidentifier,
    @CurrentDateTime datetime
AS
BEGIN
     SELECT GETDATE() AS CurrentDateTime

     SELECT UserId
       FROM dbo.aspnet_Users
      WHERE @UserId = UserId

     INSERT INTO dbo.UserLoginToday
            (UserId, UserLoginPerDay)
     VALUES (@UserId, @CurrentDateTime)
END
```

It does not write anything to my database tho. What am i doing wrong? And will this write the correct data that i want?

Comment: Why do you `SELECT UserId FROM dbo.aspnet_Users WHERE @UserId = UserId` ? If you already have UserId as a parameter, why select _the same value_ from the table!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE loginProc
   @UserId uniqueidentifier
AS
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO dbo.UserLoginToday
            (UserId, UserLoginPerDay)
     SELECT UserId, GETDATE()
       FROM dbo.aspnet_Users
      WHERE UserId = @UserId
END
```

You will need to use a procedure and not a function as functions don't allow DML (Insert /Update/Delete) statements.

No need to pass current timestamp as parameter as this can be generated inside stored procedure using `GETDATE()` and inserted into log table

Comment: What change/s was/were made? Why?

Comment: `CREATE PROCEDURE loginProc` at the top, not putting `GETDATE()` into a variable when it can be used directly.

Comment: @m hasan, what is the use of selecting `UserId` from `dbo.aspnet_Users` when you have the value in `@UserId` parameter ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, i had some problems with calling the procedure in my C# code, took some time to fix that. Then i tried your procedure and it worked perfectly. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I still have a small problem, if i login with a user that already logged in once(and thus has a userId that is already in the table) It will not add another record in the table. What can i do to fix this?

Comment: this means you have created userid as primary key / unique key in logging table... you should

Comment: this means you have created userid as primary key / unique key in logging table... you should remove key constraint from userid column and create new column with identity specification ... search identity column on google..

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to assign values to the parameters and in **WHERE** condition you have written `@UserId=UserId`, which should be `UserId=@UserId` . Try this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE loginProc
    @UserId uniqueidentifier,
    @CurrentDateTime datetime
AS
BEGIN
     SELECT @CurrentDateTime = GETDATE() AS CurrentDateTime

     SELECT @UserId=UserId
       FROM dbo.aspnet_Users
      WHERE UserId = @UserId

     INSERT INTO dbo.UserLoginToday
            (UserId, UserLoginPerDay)
     VALUES (@UserId, @CurrentDateTime)
END
```

The optimum solution is -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE loginProc
    @UserId uniqueidentifier
AS
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO dbo.UserLoginToday
            (UserId, UserLoginPerDay)
     VALUES (@UserId, GETDATE())
END
```

**Explaination:**

1. Removed the `@CurrentDateTime` parameter as it is not required to be passed from the application end

2. No need to assign current date and time to a variable and then use it in the insert statement as we can directly use it in the insert statement as `GETDATE()`

3. No need to find the `UserId` from `dbo.aspnet_users`, then assign it to the parameter variable and the use it in the insert statement. We already have the `UserId` value passed from the application end as parameter `@UserId`, which can be used directly in the insert statement.